# Adding one Dictionary object to another

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary

Is it possible to add one dictionary to another like for example:

```
Dictionary<string,int> d1=new Dictionary<string,int>()
{
   {"abc",1}
   {"def",2}
};

Dictionary<string,string> d2=new Dictionary<string,string>()
{
   {"str","fgh"}
   {"uyz","ghi"}
};
```

I need to add `d1` to `d2`. Please note that the dictionaries have different signatures.

Comment: What is your end target? do you need to merge them?

Comment: What are you really trying to do? doing this to your dictionary would make it a complete pain to try and retrieve values

Comment: What should happen when `d2` already contains `{"def", "2"}` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your values can have different types you could create third dictionary of type `DIctionary<String, Object>` and add all the items from your dictionaries into it.

```
Dictionary<string,int> d1=new Dictionary<string,int>()    
{    
      {"abc",1}    
      {"def",2}    
};

Dictionary<string,string> d2=new Dictionary<string,string>()    
{    
      {"str","fgh"}    
      {"uyz","ghi"}    
};

Dictionary<String, Object> combinedDict = new Dictionary<String, Object>();

foreach(var d1Item in d1)
    combinedDict.Add(d1Item.Key, d1Item.Value);

foreach(var d2Item in d2)
    combinedDict.Add(d2Item.Key, d2Item.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

That is only possible if you make both the same signature. So you should either revert to `object` or `string`.

Just loop over one of the dictionaries (preferably the `string,int` one), and add the values to the other one, converting its values.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Concat` + `ToDictionary`.

```
var newPairs = d1
    .Where(kv1 => !d2.ContainsKey(kv1.Key))
    .Select(kv1 => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(kv1.Key, kv1.Value.ToString()));
d2 = d2.Concat(newPairs).ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value);
```

The `Where` checks first if the second dictionary already contains a given key from the first. The `Select` converts the values to `string` and creates a `KeyValuePair<string, string>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a dictionary to another dictionary, that holds key value pairs of different types.

However, if you decide, which would the types of the key and value pairs you will hold, then you can convert one to another and add the one dictionary to the other.

For instance, let we have a dictionary called `dictionaryA`:

```
Dictionary<string, int> dictionaryA = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

and another dictionary called `dictionaryB`:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionaryB = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

Let, also that we want to add the `dictionaryA` to the `dictionaryB` and create a dictionary, which will hold key value pairs of types `string` and `string` correspondigly. Then you could try something like this:

```
foreach(var key in dictionaryA)
{
    // Check if the key is not contained in the keys collection of dictionaryB.
    // If so, add the corresponding element of the dictionaryA to the dictionaryB. 
    if(!dictionaryB.Keys.Contains(key))
        dictionaryB.Add(key, dictionaryA[key].ToString());
}
```

Comment: But you can convert values.

Comment: That's for sure. I will update my post correspondigly.